# PostgreSQL function to extract a HTTP query argument from a URL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.3

I'd like to extract a query argument from a string which represents a URL, and I'd like to do it in a stored function (there is not by chance some standard function I could use?).

In Python, this would be:

```
from urlparse import urlparse, parse_qs
def extract_oid(url):
    """
    extract the 'oid' query argument

    (simplified, no error handling)

    >>> extract_oid('http://some.host/some/path?oid=abc123&other')
    'abc123'
    """
    return parse_qs(urlparse(url).query)['oid'][0]
```

My current try in `plpgsql` is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION extract_oid (link text)
RETURNS text
AS $$
DECLARE
  pos1 integer := position('&oid=' in link);
  tail text := substring(link from pos1 + 1);
  endpos integer := position('&' in tail);
BEGIN
  if link is NULL or pos1 = 0 then
    RETURN NULL;
  ELSIF endpos = 0 then
    RETURN substring(tail from 5);
  ELSE
    RETURN substring(tail from 5 for endpos - 1);
  END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This works fine if the `oid` is the last argument in the query string and has  at least one predecessor (otherwise I'd need to recognize `?oid=` as well); however, it fails when there is another `&` following. I'd like to be sefe here ...

Something seems to be wrong with the `endpos` variable.

Can someone please enlighten me? Thank you!

I need this to work with PostgreSQL 9.3+.

**Edit:**

I found my logical error (of course I needed to subtract 5 rather than 1, silly me), but after the horse's answer, my function looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION extract_oid (url text)
RETURNS text
AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN split_part(substring(url from '[?&]oid=[^&]+'), '=', 2);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apart from using your Python code in a [Python function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpython.html), I would use a regular expression for this:

```
split_part(substring(link from 'oid=\w+'), '=', 2)
```

`substring(link from 'oid=\w+')` will return `oid=abc123` and `split_part()` will then extract the second element using `=` as the delimiter.

```
with t (url) as (
  values 
    ('http://some.host/some/path?oid=abc123&other'), 
    ('http://some.host/some/path?other&oid=def456&foo=bar')
)
select split_part(substring(url from 'oid=\w+'), '=', 2)
from t;
```

will return:

```
split_part
----------
abc123    
def456
```

I think that should work on 9.3 as well

Comment: Yes, thank you! I changed the `from` expression to `'[?&]oid=[^&]+'` to ignore `otherprefixoid` vars and allow non-word characters as well.